# Using @Schema(allowableValues=) for enum param using openapi in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, openapi

My API has a enum field in request body. When I generate swagger UI, its showing enum with allowed value as enum names. Instead of enum names, I need to set it to enum values. For that I used  @Schema(allowableValues=). This lead to a list with both values and names in swagger UI. Can I set this to values only in swagger?

My enum example :

```
 public enum Days{
  MON("Monday"),
  SUN("Sunday")
}
```

Current swagger field looks like :

> day   string Enum: [ MON, SUN ]

I want it has :

> day   string Enum: [ Monday, Sunday]

When I add @Schema(allowableValues={"Monday", "Sunday") to the enum field, Swagger becomes:

> day   string Enum: [ MON, SUN, Monday, Sunday]

Any solution is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Could you please add your swagger image?

Comment: What's the alternative for annotation based implementation

Answer (score 10):

use

```
@Schema(type = "string", allowableValues = { "Monday", "Sunday" })
```

Comment: Thank you for joining StackOverFlow. While your answer may be practical, a little more explanation can help readers understand the mechanism of your code :)

Comment: This doesn't work. It simply shows a dropdown with the two comma separated values as an element of the dropdown instead of individual dropdown options.

Answer (score 6):

Can be achieved by overriding toString for enum. No need to use @Schema

```
 @Override
  public String toString() {
    return value;
  }
```

Comment: For me worked annotating the `toString` with `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonValue`.

Comment: I had an enum with a value and a different name. I was able to do it by setting @JsonValue on the getName, and keeping the toString() override to get the value that I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Jackson then swagger added support to use the values defined in the annotations @JsonProperty/@JsonValue which was included in v2.1.3 https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/releases/tag/v2.1.3

So you can just write

```
 public enum Days{
     @JsonProperty("Monday")
     MON,
     @JsonProperty("Sunday")
     SUN
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume your request is defined in the `Request` class and your request attribute is `day`. So what you can easily do is add swagger-ui annotation `@Schema` as follows.

```
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema;

class Request {
    @Schema(type = "string", allowableValues = { "Monday", "Sunday" })
    String day;
}
```