# How can have springdoc-openapi use the @JsonValue enum format without changing toString?

Tags: java, jackson, swagger, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

I have a Spring Boot application using [springdoc-openapi](https://springdoc.org) to generate Swagger API documentation for my controllers.  One of the enums used in the JSON request/response has a different JSON representation than its `value`/`toString()`.  This is achieved using the Jackson [`@JsonValue`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonValue.html) annotation:

```java
public enum Suit {
    HEARTS("Hearts"), DIAMONDS("Diamonds"), CLUBS("Clubs"), SPADES("Spades");

    @JsonValue
    private final String jsonValue;

    Suit(String jsonValue) { this.jsonValue = jsonValue; }
}
```

However, the generated Swagger API docs use the enum value (specifically, the value of `toString()`) rather than the JSON representation (per `@JsonValue`) when listing the enum values:

```json
{
  "openapi": "3.0.1",
  "info": { "title": "OpenAPI definition", "version": "v0" },
  "servers": [
    { "url": "http://localhost:8080", "description": "Generated server url" }
  ],
  "paths": { ... },
  "components": {
    "schemas": {
      "PlayingCard": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "suit": {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [ "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades" ]
          },
          "value": { "type": "integer", "format": "int32" }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There is closed issue [#1101](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/1101) in the springdoc-openapi project which requests allowing `@JsonValue` to affect the enum serialization.  However, that issue was [closed](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/1101#issuecomment-806731501) since no PR was submitted for it.

How can I get the enum list to match the actual JSON type accepted/returned by the REST endpoint, and not the `toString()` values?

My first thought to solving this issue was to use the [`@Schema(allowableValues = {...}]`](https://javadoc.io/static/io.swagger.core.v3/swagger-annotations/2.1.10/io/swagger/v3/oas/annotations/media/Schema.html) annotation from [Swagger Core](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core).  However, whether by bug or by design, this adds to the list of values, rather than replacing it:

```java
@Schema(allowableValues = {"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"})
public enum Suit {
    HEARTS("Hearts"), DIAMONDS("Diamonds"), CLUBS("Clubs"), SPADES("Spades");
    // ...
}
```

```json
"suit": {
  "type": "string",
  "enum": [
    "HEARTS", 
    "DIAMONDS",
    "CLUBS",
    "SPADES",
    "Hearts",
    "Diamonds",
    "Clubs",
    "Spades"
  ]
}
```

### Reproducible Example

```groovy
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations:2.1.10'
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.5.10'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
}
```

```java
package com.example.springdoc;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonValue;

public class PlayingCard {
    private Suit suit;
    private Integer value;

    public Suit getSuit() { return suit; }
    public void setSuit(Suit suit) { this.suit = suit; }
    public Integer getValue() { return value; }
    public void setValue(Integer value) { this.value = value; }

    public enum Suit {
        HEARTS("Hearts"), DIAMONDS("Diamonds"), CLUBS("Clubs"), SPADES("Spades");

        @JsonValue
        private final String jsonValue;

        Suit(String jsonValue) { this.jsonValue = jsonValue; }
    }
}
```

```
package com.example.springdoc;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/playingCard")
public class PlayingCardController {
    @PostMapping
    public PlayingCard echo(@RequestBody PlayingCard card) {
        return card;
    }
}
```

Swagger URL: `http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs`

Comment: There is an option with [JsonProperty](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-enums#3-using-jsonproperty), [JsonCreator](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-enums#4-using-jsoncreator) and overriding [`toString()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62677965/using-schemaallowablevalues-for-enum-param-using-openapi-in-spring-boot). Can you check whether these work pls?

Comment: `JsonProperty` and (as alluded to in the question) `toString()` work.  No such luck with `JsonCreator` (though given that creates an enum from a value and doesn't declaratively specify a mapping, I don't think there's really any reasonable way it _could_ work).

Comment: @aksappy Thanks; I've expanded the `JsonProperty` suggestion into an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was due to bug [#3998](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/3998) in versions of [Swagger Core](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core) prior to 2.2.5.  In those versions of the library, `@JsonValue` is handled properly when on a public method, but not when on a field.  Upgrading to version 2.2.5 of Swagger Core or later will cause the example to work as desired without modification.

Alternatively, for versions of Swagger Core before 2.2.5, adding a public accessor method will have the desired effect:

```java
public enum Suit {
    HEARTS("Hearts"), DIAMONDS("Diamonds"), CLUBS("Clubs"), SPADES("Spades");

    private final String jsonValue;

    Suit(String jsonValue) { this.jsonValue = jsonValue; }

    @JsonValue
    public String getJsonValue() {
        return jsonValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A [`PropertyCustomizer`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.springdoc/springdoc-openapi-common/1.5.10/org/springdoc/core/customizers/PropertyCustomizer.html) Spring bean can be created to customize the property.  This can be done either for the specific enum type, or globally for all enums.

### Type-specific customizer with explicit list

The following customizer will explicitly set the enum values for the specific enum type:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType;
import io.swagger.v3.core.converter.AnnotatedType;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.media.Schema;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.media.StringSchema;
import org.springdoc.core.customizers.PropertyCustomizer;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.List;

@Component
public class SuitPropertyCustomizer implements PropertyCustomizer {
    @Override
    public Schema customize(Schema property, AnnotatedType type) {
        if (property instanceof StringSchema && isSuit(type)) {
            property.setEnum(List.of("Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"));
        }

        return property;
    }

    private boolean isSuit(AnnotatedType type) {
        return type.getType() instanceof JavaType t
                && t.isTypeOrSubTypeOf(Suit.class);
    }
}
```

### Global enum customizer using `@JsonValue`

The following customizer will use the Jackson String representation for all enum types, meaning the `@JsonValue` annotation will be used where applicable.

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import io.swagger.v3.core.converter.AnnotatedType;
import io.swagger.v3.core.util.Json;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.media.Schema;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.media.StringSchema;
import org.springdoc.core.customizers.PropertyCustomizer;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Component
public class EnumValuePropertyCustomizer implements PropertyCustomizer {
    @Override
    public Schema customize(Schema property, AnnotatedType type) {
        if (property instanceof StringSchema && isEnumType(type)) {
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = Json.mapper();

            property.setEnum(Arrays.stream(((JavaType) type.getType()).getRawClass().getEnumConstants())
                    .map(e -> objectMapper.convertValue(e, String.class))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
        }
        return property;
    }

    private boolean isEnumType(AnnotatedType type) {
        return type.getType() instanceof JavaType t && t.getType().isEnumType();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to replace the `@JsonValue` implementation with `@JsonProperty`:

```java
public enum Suit {
    @JsonProperty("Hearts") HEARTS,
    @JsonProperty("Diamonds") DIAMONDS,
    @JsonProperty("Clubs") CLUBS,
    @JsonProperty("Spades") SPADES;
}
```

Note that this does result in some duplication if the value is programmatically needed, as it will need to be specified both in `@JsonProperty` as well as a value on the enum.